# RRDTool for php in Windows

Tags: php, windows, rrdtool

I want to use the rrdtool extension for php to create graphs in windows. I need an php_rrdtools.dll or something like that.

Can anyone help me to create the php extensions to work with rrdtools or tell me where i can download such extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, since rrd is pecl extension compiled from source:

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild